# ¿Como puedo centrar este scrolltext o scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

Mi cuadro de texto queda en el centro y no he podido colocarlo en otro lado, los atributos que tiene de columna y fila solo sirven para mover la barra de dezplazamiento...ayuda por favor

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('NAES Solver')
root.geometry('700x350')


#Etiqueta variable y cuadro de texto con barra de desplazamiento horizontal
etiqueta = tk.Label(text="Variables", fg="black", bg="yellow").place(x=30,y=8)

textContainer = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")

text = tk.Text(textContainer, padx= 20, pady=2, width=10, height=1, wrap="none", borderwidth=0)

textHsb = tk.Scrollbar(textContainer, orient="horizontal", command=text.xview)

text.configure(xscrollcommand=textHsb.set)

text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

textHsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

textContainer.pack(side="top")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal el `import` inicial, que debería ser  `from tkinter import tk`, pero esto no está relacionado con la pregunta.

El problema es que los objetos `text` y `textHsb` se posicionan dentro de su `Frame`, pero éste no se ha posicionado dentro de la ventana que lo contiene. El Frame se ha ajustado al tamaño exacto de sus dos "hijos" (`text` y `textHsb`). Aunque cambies sus atributos de columna y fila, eso moverán a los hijos dentro del frame, pero no al frame dentro de la ventana.

Y colocar un frame dentro de una ventana no tiene muchas opciones (no admite `grid()` ni `place()`. Simplemente se puede poner "arriba", "abajo", "izquierda" o "derecha", quedando centrado en el lado que indiques.

Quizás se vea mejor si ponemos fondo rojo al frame y azul a la ventana raiz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, el fondo rojo es apenas visible. El frame ocupa lo mismo que sus contenidos y está empaquetado en la zona de arriba de la ventana raíz, siendo el resto "padding" hasta rellenar esa ventana. La etiqueta ha sido colocada en una posición absoluta también dentro de la ventana raiz.

Una posible solución es meter la etiqueta dentro del frame, en vez de colocarla en la raiz. De este modo la raiz tendrá un solo "hijo" (el frame) y el frame tendrá tres hijos (la etiqueta, el texto y la barra de scroll), y puedes usar columnnas y filas para colocarlos:

```
textContainer = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1,relief="sunken", bg="red")
etiqueta = tk.Label(textContainer, text="Variables", fg="black", bg="yellow").grid(column=0, row=0)
# ...
text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
textHsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
```

El resultado sería ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves por los colores, el frame (rojo) contiene ahora tanto a la etiqueta como a la entrada de texto, lo que nos permite colocarlos uno respecto a otro. El propio frame sigue saliendo centrado en posición "top", pero si quieres puedes cambiarlo al empaquetarlo, mediante `textContainer.pack(side="left")` por ejemplo.

Alternativamente puedes pasarle los parámetros `textContainer.pack(fill="both", expand=True)` para que llene todo el espacio disponible en la ventana, en cuyo caso el `side` ya es irrelevante y saldrá todo pegado arriba a la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(ya no se ve nada azul, pues todo el área del padre ha sido ocupada por el frame hijo).

Código completo (y quitando ya los horribles colores usados para depuración):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('NAES Solver')
root.geometry('500x150')

#Etiqueta variable y cuadro de texto con barra de desplazamiento horizontal
textContainer = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1,relief="sunken")
etiqueta = tk.Label(textContainer, text="Variables", fg="black", bg="yellow").grid(column=0, row=0)

text = tk.Text(textContainer, padx= 20, pady=2, width=10, height=1, wrap="none", borderwidth=0)
textHsb = tk.Scrollbar(textContainer, orient="horizontal", command=text.xview)
text.configure(xscrollcommand=textHsb.set)
text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
textHsb.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")

textContainer.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Y esto es lo que se ve (he escrito ya una cadena larga en la zona de texto para que se vea la barra de scroll:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, te agradezco mucho :)...bonito dia

Comment: @ChepeJimenez por ejemplo, acá dices que muchas gracias pero no marcas la respuesta como aceptada (el tick a la izquierda junto a los votos positivos/negativos)